# Getting GCP usage via API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've spent hours going through Google Cloud Platform (GCP) documentation but I can't seem to find a way to retreive usage (in dollars) of different GCP services. Is this even possible?

Comment: Consider trying an alternative https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery. Once data is already in BQ then you can use BQ API https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/

Comment: ... I think @Christopher nailed it.  It also appears we can export to a JSON or CSV file in GCS ... see https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file

Comment: Yeah, those seem like the only ways to do it. AWS has such a convenient api... If you want to write an anwer I'll "best answer" it.